# Change or rename android resource files from another app by content provider

Tags: android, resources, android-contentprovider

Say I have two apps A and B. I want to change/rename some resource files(in drawable folder or strings) of app A from B. Is it possible to share resource data of A in Context Provider and change/rename it from B when A is not running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't possible to change anything in the res folder. Resources are read-only at runtime.

Comment: But I want to change resources of app A when its not running. Can I do that somehow.

Comment: You can't change resources once APK is generated. Resources are read-only.